# Probability of meeting at the corner of city streets betwe

Tags: probability

> Two people agree to meet each other at the corner of two city streets
>   between 1pm and 2pm. However, neither will wait for the other for more
>   than 30 minutes. If each person is equally likely to arrive at any
>   time during the one hour period, determine the probability that they
>   will in fact meet.

This question is very similar to [Probability of two people meeting during a certain time.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359098/probability-of-two-people-meeting-during-a-certain-time)
But I'm afraid I'll have to ask again, because it's not quite what my query is about.

I've tried letting X and Y be the two random variables, and they are independent of each other.
I tried phrasing it in terms of $P(|X-Y|<30) $ but I don't know how to solve this, as i don't know the individual probability of either X and Y? 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Sorry in advance if I seem to be repeating the question (in link) and for any wrong title or tag labelling.

I have also thought of another method:

If A arrives before B, then the probability that he arrives during first  half an hour is  0.5 . He'll then wait for  0.5 hours. If He arrives during the last  half an hour hours, with proability 0.5 . He then waits for  0.5  hours on average. Thus his total wait time is  0.5*0.5*2=0.5. For A and B to meet, B must arrive when A is waiting. Thus the probability that B arrived when A was waiting is 0.5 . Similarly if B arrives before A, the probability that they meet is 0.5 . Thus, Total probability that they meet is  1. Where did I go wrong? As the answer suggested is 0.75.

Comment: Aren't $X$ and $Y$ both uniformly distributed between $0$ and $60$?  (And I assume it is intended that they arrive independently, though it's not stated explicitly in the problem description.)

Comment: @BrianTung, However, if using uniform distribution, if I do invnorm on GDC, it doesn't mean that I can solve it? (as i don't know the mean and the variance?) Pls advise.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.  Why isn't this question like the one you link to?

Comment: @BrianTung, as the previous one is asking for geometrical solution, however, I am trying to solve it with probabilities. Just different methods of approaching the solution. Sorry if I am wrong in thinking that they are different.

Comment: The variables are not normally distributed, so you cannot use mean and variance.  You can integrate the probability density function over the region where the two people meet; since that function is constant and the region is more or less as depicted in that other question, the methods are essentially identical.

Comment: Thank you, @BrianTung, I have now edited my question about a different type of query.

Comment: Probability is 75% according the following simulation (in R).                     "n <- 10^5 # number of trials
a <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 60)
b <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 60)
sum(abs(a-b) < 30)/n"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The R code below essentially repeats @snoram's nice simulation, but using
only 50,000 points. Then I go on to plot the points in the square with
vertices at $(0,0)$ and $(60,60)$, with the points corresponding
to the condition that the two people meet plotted in light blue.

From there, it is obvious that the two excluded regions (black)
each have $1/8$th of the  area. Because the joint distribution
is uniform on the square this means that the probability of the
'condition' is $3/4.$

Of course, you can draw the boundaries of the condition, and
thus solve the problem, without simulation. (It is $not$ necessary
to know the distribution of $|X - Y|$.) In integral notation,
you need $\int\int_C 1/60^2\,dx\,dy,$ where $C$ is the region
corresponding to the condition. You'd have to break $C$ up
into two parts in order to set numerical limits on the integral
signs. But I think the geometrical argument suffices.

```
 m = 50000
 x = runif(m, 0, 60);  y = runif(m, 0, 60)
 cond = (abs(x-y) < 30);  mean(cond)
 ## 0.74938  # aprx answer; actual answer 3/4
 plot(x, y, pch=".")
 points(x[cond], y[cond], pch=".", col="skyblue2")
```

[image]